# c# SQLite loop error

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

I am an ObjectiveC coder, trying to write a Windows 10 app,
I have got stuck trying to query an existing database, to get started I just need to pull all the names in column "RM_N" from table "storeNames" from dB "fieldnames.sql" and populate the ComboBox, I would like to use a string Query because I will be moving onto a more complex query next.

I think I am going wrong somewhere with the loop, I am getting the message

***"Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range."***

with a arrow pointing to ***rmNamePick.ItemsSource = names;***

```
  private class storeNames
        {
            public string RM_N { get; set; }
        }

        private void loadRMnames()
        {
            string fileName = "fieldnames.sql";
            string _path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, fileName);

            if (_path != null)
            {
                using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), _path))
                {
                    var regionNames = conn.Query<storeNames>(@"SELECT RM_N FROM storeNames;");
                    foreach (var names in regionNames)
                    {
                        if (names == null)
                        {
                            rmNamePick.ItemsSource = @"No Data";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rmNamePick.Items.Clear();
                            rmNamePick.ItemsSource = names;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: At the minute you're passing `names` which is an instance of `storeNames` to `rmNamePick.ItemsSource`: if you want to pass the actual string value, pass in `names.RM_N`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I have changed rmNamePick.ItemSource = name.RM_N; but still get this error                                                                                                             "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in VAPRA.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range."

Comment: I also notice that you're setting the `rmNamePick.ItemsSource` in every iteration of the loop, i.e. you're overwriting it for each storeName: that doesn't look right, don't you want to add _all_ the values to it?

Comment: .. and `Path.Combine` will never return null (it throws if passed a null string)

Comment: Something like `rmNamePick.ItemsSource = regionNames.Select(r => r ?? "No Data")` would make more sense in the C# world.

Comment: yes I needed all the values, not sure where I am going wrong there thou, should there be some sort of "Return" statement?

Comment: while I had paused typing, you had kindly made two more obsivations, which are greatly appreciated, the second one "rmNamePick.ItemsSource = regionNames.Select(r => r ?? "No Data")" I don't fully understand the code is this to populate the "ComboBox" or the error checking "rmNamePick.ItemsSource = @"No Data";
"

Comment: That code is using Linq to select the values to populate the combo box: the `??` is called the "null coalescing operator", which I don't believe is implemented in objC, and means "if the left hand value is null, use the right hand value". The line is thus (broadly)  saying "Get me a list of the values, and if any of them are null, substitute "No Data" for the value", and use that to populate the combo box" …

Comment: … this would mean though that you could have multiple entries of "No Data", which would be confusing: perhaps something (pseudo) like "If no values are returned, set "No data" as the ItemsSource, otherwise use the non-null values in the list of names returned"?

Comment: Thank you, that helps me better understand, I think you are saying this could populate the "ComboBox" & error check at the same time. any chance you could show where this would fit into my existing code?

Comment: if I use " Debug.WriteLine(names.RM_N);" it writes the expected results, so it must be something to do with "rmNamePick.ItemsSource = names.RM_N;" ?

Comment: I think my problem is the "foreach" gets the results one by one, but I need to load the all the results into an array & then pass this to the ComboBox, does this look right from my code & what do I need to add to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I got there eventually

```
private void loadRMnames()
        {

            List<string> namesArray = new List<string>();
            string fileName = "fieldnames.sql";
            string _path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, fileName);


                using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), _path))
                {
                    var regionNames = conn.Query<storeNames>(@"SELECT RM_N FROM storeNames;");
                foreach (var names in regionNames)
                {
                    namesArray.Add(names.RM_N);

                }


                rmNamePick.Items.Clear();
                rmNamePick.ItemsSource = namesArray;


            }
            }
```